# Regex to match a complex JSON value

Tags: json, regex

I have a JSON in the form:

```
"A":
{
   "A1": "something",
   "A2": 1234,
   "A3": true
}
```

How can I use regex to capture A and everything inside of it?

Comment: What hinders you to simply parse the JSON? Evaluating JSON with a regex sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @maio290 there are some fields in the file that do not comply with json formatting so I thought just grabbing the ones that do would be easier. I just want the info from inside a specific field

Answer (score 1):

Does not look good but try once.

```
"A":[\n{\n]*[[:blank:]"A-Z0-9:a-z,\n]*}
```